# Adding HTML elements via jQuery causing a bug in Etalage Plugin (Function Collision Bug)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**TLDR:** A bug I can’t find is preventing the plugin from working when HTML elements are injected via jQuery.

**Summary:** The plugin is designed if you have control over the HTML, but since I don't I’m trying to coronate an image tag to gain mouseover "hoverzoom" attributes but when I add the necessary HTML attributes through jQuery functions such as `.wrap();` `.after();` and `.addClass();`, all images disappear. I have to do it via jQuery DOM manipulation because I don’t have control over the HTML directly. (Don’t ask, long story, has to be jQuery). The weird thing is, on the same sample environment (see below), if I add the HTML elements, ID's and classes, the plugin works. But if I try to add all the necessary attributes to a bare image tag, it disappears.

**Theory:** The image tags seem to disappear both when the `<ul>` has an `id="etalage"` (as the plugin deployment directions dictate) and when the `<img>` tags have the respective classes designating them as source and thumb images. My theory is there's some CSS "display:none" rule being invoked but if this was true, then shouldn't the other example, which works on the page, also not work?

**The plugin:** Etalage on Code Canyon (I'd post the link but Stack Overflow tells me I'm too junior to post more than one link)

**Example Page of the bug:** [in the wild](http://igavelauctions.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/etalage_bug.html) (Comments can be seen in inspector)

My code (that doesn't work), HTML:

```
<img id="thumbImage" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg" alt="" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#thumbImage').wrap('<ul id="etalage"><li /></ul>')
.addClass('etalage_thumb_image')
.after('<img class="etalage_source_image target" />'); $('.etalage_source_image')
.attr('src', 'http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg'); 
});
```

According to Etalage, this is the code that does work.

HTML

```
<ul id="etalage">
<li>
<img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="xyz.jpg">
<img class="etalage_source_image target" src="xyz.jpg">
</li>
</ul>
```

I'm so lost. I appreciate in advance if anyone can help. I did post over on their help forum but SO has been so helpful in debugging my code in the past.

Comment: If you add extra links in a comment, someone will edit your post and put them in for you. I agree, a link to the plugin you refer to is necessary.

Comment: Would you reword "coronate", btw? - not sure what you mean there.

Comment: Did you knew, that creating elements in javascript by hand (typing elements as string) might caught a weird problem. Javascript has build-in function for creating elements  `var div = Object.createElement('div')` and for adding child: `div.appendChild(anotherElement)`

Comment: You can't have more than one element on the page with the same id and there is no guarantee the order of  execution when adding handlers to the `document.ready()`.  See answer below for more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

1. you are using ids to apply the plugin in the hoverZoomjquery.etalage.min.js script. That means you are injecting a second DOM element with the same id.  Ids are supposed to be unique.  I fixed this by making the ids unique adding a class "etalage" and using $(".etalage") instead of $("#etalage").
2. you are using document.ready to do the DOM manipulation as well as apply the plugin except they are different files.  There is no guarantee as what handler will fire first.  The plugin could get applied before you actually inject the DOM objects.  I moved the call to apply the plugin to the handler where you do the DOM manipulations so I can make sure it is called after I inject the elements.

I apologize for the "hacky" fix, but it should illustrate the problem.  This makes the code work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>iG Hoverzoom v1</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://igavelauctions.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/css/hoverZoomEtalage.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://igavelauctions.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/hoverZoomjquery.etalage.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="hoverZoomThumbWidths.js"></script>-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('#thumbImage').wrap('<ul id="etalage2" class="etalage"><li></li></ul>').addClass('etalage_thumb_image').after('<img class="etalage_source_image target"/>');

            $('.etalage_source_image').attr('src', 'http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg');

            $('.etalage').etalage({
                thumb_image_width: 300,
                thumb_image_height: 400,
                source_image_width: 900,
                source_image_height: 1200
            });


        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>


    <div>
        <!-- Example of code that works -->

        <ul id="etalage1" class="etalage">
            <li>
                <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg">
                <img class="etalage_source_image target" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg">
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>

    <div>


        <!-- This is image tag that I'm trying to turn into Etalage through jQuery operators It disappears when the page is rendered. -->
        <img id="thumbImage" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>


</body>


</html>
```